# Get specific line from a txt file in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a dictionary txt file that looks like this :

```
Aaliyah
Aaron
Abandon
Abandoned
Abatement
Abba
Abbey
Abbott
Abbreviation
Abbreviations
Abby
...
```

I'm trying to write a function that looks something like `getLineFrom('dictionary.txt', 6)` that simply gets what is in line 6 (for example) (Abba) from the dictionary.txt file

But i don't want to load the whole dictionary (with 20k words) into javascript and then traverse that list to get to my line, I just  want it to grab line X from a txt file

Comment: Assuming you're on serverside, use a database instead (SQLite3 is perfectly fine for your use case). With a flat text file, there is no choice but to read the first X lines to get to line X. On clientside, you'd typically either ask a server to send you one, or load the whole file.

Comment: Well clientside JavaScript does not have that ability.

Comment: @epascarello OP has not specified whether it is clientside or serverside, so I talked about both...

Comment: Your comment was not there when I wrote mine. But to comment on yours, there is no need for a DB on the server with nodejs https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_example_read_file_stream_line_by_line.